# Запрос с клиента идёт на самого себя же

Tags: vue.js, nginx, docker

В докере 4 контейнера: vuejs (8080port), nginx(80port), laravel(8000) и mysql.

С клиента посылаю запрос на 80 порт в запросах, но в логах запрос идет на свой же 8080 порт.
[image: Логи]

Конфиг nginx:

```
worker_processes 4;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;

        location / {
            root  /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index index.html index.htm;
            include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. запуская локально, запрос уходит куда надо, но запуская в контейнере запрос всё также идет на самого себя же

Comment: «С клиента посылаю запрос» — где и как посылаете?

Comment: Конфиг nginx очень странный. Кажется в нём должны быть настроены проксирования в vue и laravel.

Comment: А почему html, а не php?